# why can't I change the gnome login-screen logo?

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, gnome

From the dconf-editor I find that the logo shown in login-screen can be changed,so I made some logoes which are the same size and same type of the original logo（even more,I make sure they have the same permission as the original one）.And I put these logoes in the **"/lib/plymouth"**(just like the original one),then change the setting by dconf-editor to show my logo on login-screen.


But,it **does not** work! I have tried log out and log in,restart my pc,still does not work.The login-screen still show the old logo .

ps:this is my environment:
gnome-session:GNOME Shell 3.10.4
ubuntu：3.13.0-48-generic

Anyone could help?
thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To apply the changes:

```
 sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: I tried the command.But still show the old logo.By the way, I am using the gdm not the lightdm.

Comment: The simplest way is to replace images in the default plymouth theme. Find it in `/lib/plymouth/themes`.

Comment: I made it by change the name of my to logo to the old one,and change the old one to another name.And now it works well.Thank you a lot!:)